# S3FS and Fuse, scale out or scale up

Tags: amazon-s3, fuse, s3fs

I have an infra where I have multiple machines (eg FTP servers, get/put and Samba/NFS servers) that need to share out the same (HA) storage. So I figured to use s3fs and fuse. I got this all setup and this works fine, I have two servers each exposing the same bucket via FTP/SMB/NFS.

Now, when I have more and more servers that need access to the same bucket, what is the best alternative? Just install Fuse on all boxes and let 'em all mount the same bucket (scale out) or put the currently setup two machines in front of S3 and use the NFS/SMB shares from there (and thus scale up on the front machines)?

Any idea what is the best approach? Normally I tend to scale out, but I am not too familiar with s3fs and Fuse (or S3).

so: S3 <-> AppA, B and C | OR | S3 <-> NAS_WITH NFS/SMB/FTP <-> AppA, B and C

Any comments welcome! Grtz, Ronald

Comment: Neither. It highly depends on the use case but, generally, S3 is not designed for this and s3fs is not suitable for production use.

Comment: why would you say that s3fs is not suitable for production use? It is not high traffic (like home shares orso), it is just to store some files, but many servers need them occasionally (say 1 server access per 5 minutes, and 50 servers tops). Files are around 60k.

Comment: First of all, it is not a distributed Filesystem, there is no synchronization between multiple nodes "mounting" the same bucket. Anyway, if it is extremely low and non-important data/traffic then I guess you would mount it on each machine.

Comment: And serving it out with one node at a time? Just another one as hot standby? So one node that mounts S3 and make that available with NFS/Samba/FTP? You don't have to worry about multiple nodes that do not sync...Or still not production proof?

Comment: What you will probably want is [EFS](https://aws.amazon.com/efs/), however, it is not yet fully supported. It will soon be.